# Have a trouble to use generic when create a base controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I would like to create a base controller  with generic like this

```
@RestController
public class BaseController<T extends BaseEntity, S extends BaseServiceI<T, D extends BaseDao<T>>> {
    @Autowired
    private HttpServletRequest mRequest;
    @Autowired
    private HttpServletResponse mResponse;

    @Autowired
    private S service;
```

But as you can see in this picture,there have a compile error from IDEA.

[the code of base controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TgbNW.png)

Does anyone know what the problem is?
Here's the "BaseService"'s code and it's no any problem

```
public interface BaseServiceI<T, V extends BaseDao<T>> {
```

I have take your(@Piotr Żmudzin) changes and it's works for me,Thank you very much!

But there would cause an another question when I use this way to get a service instance。Is this a wrong way to get an instance?@Piotr Żmudzin

```
public class ProjectInfoController extends BaseController<ProjectInfo, ProjectInfoServiceI, ProjectInfoDao> {
```

issue：

```
Consider marking one of the beans as @Primary, updating the consumer to accept multiple beans, or using @Qualifier to identify the bean that should be consumed

[2020-12-15 22:35:09:719] Failed to read the entry class, please make sure the accuracy of the registration certificate!Error creating bean with name 'baseController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'service'; nested exception is
```

Answer (score 1):

Your type parameters are incorrect, change them

from:

```
<T extends BaseEntity, S extends BaseServiceI<T, D extends BaseDao<T>>>
```

to:

```
<T extends BaseEntity, S extends BaseServiceI<T, D>, D extends BaseDao<T>>
```

Comment: There take a new issue to me,can you help me take a look too?

Comment: If you have two interface implementations and you are trying to inject one of them, you need to mark one of them as `@Primary` or use a `@Qualifier`.